# Azure Pipelines: multiline parameter

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, azure-pipelines, pipeline, multiline

Is it possible in the azure pipeline to pass a multi-line parameter?
If `type` is a `string`, you can't even write with a newline.
If on the other hand the `type` is `object`, you can enter multi-line, but all EOLs in the variable will be removed.

```
parameters:
- name: Multiline
  type: object
```

[image]

If I save the parameter to a text file, the result is one-line

```
- bash: |
    echo ${{ parameters.Multiline }} >> script.txt
    cat script.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think multiline parameters are not supported natively but you can use `object` to pass a multiline string. The way it can be done is by adding a yaml object that will contain the multiline string:

eg.

```yaml
foo: |
  Multiline
  text
  in 
  parameter
```

Then you can access `foo` by writing `${{ parameters.Multiline.foo }}`.

This is the pipeline code:

```
parameters:
- name: Multiline
  type: object
  
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - bash: |
      cat >> script.txt << EOL
      ${{ parameters.Multiline.foo }}
      EOL
        
      cat script.txt
```

Comment: Can parameters be one line with type on the same line? Or more compact, line wise?

Comment: DevOps complains that I am not passing the Multiline parameter when it parses the pipeline and template.  In the pipeline I have a parameter called foo, but the template is expecting a parameter called Multiline.  Whant am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on the original use case, but here's how you can do this when passing a parameter to a template, using the pipe `|` syntax.

`print-string-to-file.yml`

```
# Prints a string to a file then prints the contents of the file
parameters:
  - name: string_to_print
    type: string

steps:
  - script: |
      cat >> output.txt << EOL
      ${{ parameters.string_to_print }}
      EOL
      
      cat output.txt
```

`pipeline.yml`

```
# Demonstrates how to pass a multi-line string to a template.
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job: print_file_contents
        steps:
        - template: print-string-to-file.yml
          parameters:
            string_to_print: |
              Hello world!
              This parameter contains a string
              which spreads over multiple lines.
              Can ADO parameters handle it?
```

Log output:

```
Hello world!
This file contains lots of strings.
Representing different bits of data.
Can ADO parameters handle them all?
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @murli-prajapati is right but boy it took some time to get this right. And i think part of the reason was not having full text which shows how to set the parameter. Just adding couple more stuff on Murli's answer so that it clarifies more if someone run into this issue in future. Also added default value on parameter in case if anyone needs it. If don't then you can use it without default value.

*filename: custom-template.yml*

```
parameters:
- name: Multiline
  type: object
  default:
    list: |
      John
      Doe

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - bash: |
      cat >> script.txt << EOL
      ${{ parameters.Multiline.foo }}
      EOL

      cat script.txt
```

*filename: main.yml*

```
trigger:
  - feature

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

resoures:
  repositories
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: team-project/yaml-template

stages:
- template: custom-template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Multiline: 
      foo: |
        Multiline
        text
        in
        parameter
```